# Call another method in Unit Test in same class

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, testing

We have a unit test that inside of this unit reference another method in my service. Should I call another method in current unit test or use mocking solution?

In my test case we call reference to method `ChooseDoor()` that do some operation and after that we call Act method `SwitchDoor()`, we should use some mocking or this approach is ok? Because reference method and act that we call, they are in the same class and don't have any dependency to other class.

```
public class GameService
{
 public Door ChoosesDoor()
 {
 //some logic
 }

 public Door SwitchDoor()
 {
 //some logic
 }
}


[Fact]
public void switch_door_should_return_a_new_door_with_a_valid_state_that_chooses()
{
 //Arrange
 var oldChoosesDoor =_game.ChoosesDoor();

 //Act
 var newDoor = _game.SwitchDoor();

 //Assert
 oldChoosesDoor.DoorState.ShouldBe(State.Stateless);
 newDoor.DoorState.ShouldBe(State.Chosen);
 oldChoosesDoor.DoorState.ShouldNotBe(newDoor.DoorState);
 oldChoosesDoor.Number.ShouldBeInRange(1,3);
}
```

Comment: that depends on what exactly you want to test. Is this a unit-test or some integration-test?

Comment: @HimBromBeere it's unit test.

Comment: Well, what you are testing is basically a sideeffect of `SwitchDoor` on the state of it's class. That means you are expecting a difference in state after the call from the state of before the call. That means you need both representations to be able to say if the call had the expected effect ...

Comment: you should probably not mock your SuT.

Comment: @HimBromBeere we don't have any Io call and only need to run first method and after that check method 2. Those methods are in same class.

Comment: `switch_door_should_return_a_new_door_with_a_valid_state_that_chooses()` seriously?

Answer (score 0):

It is fine as long as you are e2e testing but, for unit testing, by doing this you are forcing dependencies from one another.
Although you as a developer tend to reuse code as much as possible, for unit testing you would follow the AAA (Arrange Act Assert) pattern no matter how repetitive it seems to be.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Calling other methods of the class under the test as part of setup is totally ok.
By doing this you will kinda test another method as well. Notice that you are testing a behaviour of your code.

Even in unit testing, unit is a unit of the behaviour, which can include single or multiple different methods or types.

"Test in isolation" means that tests should be isolated from other tests.